# Powershell Add-Member to Object if exists, else New-Object

Tags: powershell, object

I'm trying to understand PowerShell a little better for work and have run in to an issue with one of my little projects. I want to loop through an array of Performance Counters and get the cookedvalue (Example: \memory\available mbytes would have a cooked value of 4096 to show 4GB available memory).

I want my output to be in JSON format to be structured like the following:

```
PERFORMANCE
    MEMORY
       PAGE_FAULTS/SEC = 673
       %_COMMITED_MEMORY_IN_USE = 12
       AVAILABLE_MBYTES = 4096
       COMMITTED_BYTES = 3243
    PROCESS(*)
       %_PROCESSOR_TIME = 54
    LOGICALDISK(C:)
       DISK_READS/SEC = 462
```

This is the current state of my script below. I'm struggling to grasp object management and could really do with a nudge in the right direction. The script works fine (it fetches the cookedvalues using Get-Counter and I can print the results) it's just adding the data to the object in a logical manner that I'm having issues with.

```
$CounterPathList = "\Memory\Page Faults/sec", "\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use", "\Memory\Available MBytes", "\Memory\Committed Bytes", "\Process(*)\% Processor Time", "\LogicalDisk(C:)\Disk Reads/sec" 

$Performance = New-Object –TypeName PSObject

ForEach($CounterPath in $CounterPathList){

    $PathRoot = ($CounterPath.split('\')[1]).ToUpper()
    $Name = (($CounterPath -replace '.*\\') -replace " ","_").ToUpper()
    $Value=((Get-Counter($CounterPath)).countersamples | select -property cookedvalue).cookedvalue

    if(!($Performance | Where-Object -Property Name -eq $PathRoot)){
        Add-Member -InputObject $Performance -MemberType NoteProperty –Name $PathRoot –Value "" -force
    }else{
        Add-Member -InputObject $Performance.$PathRoot -MemberType NoteProperty –Name $Name –Value $Value -force
    }

}

$Performance | ConvertTo-JSON
```

The script above currently outputs:

```
$Performance | ConvertTo-JSON
{
    "MEMORY":  "",
    "PROCESS(*)":  "",
    "LOGICALDISK(C:)":  ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the PowerShell JSON cmdlets (`-lt 5.1`) are overly inflexible - in general they work a lot better with `PSCustomObject`s. (see end of this post for one example, another is that V6 `ConvertFrom-Json` adds a `-AsHashtable` switch) Here's one way to get what you want working with a simple `Hashtable`:

```
$counters = Get-Counter $wanted | select -ExpandProperty CounterSamples;
$toJson = @{ 'PERFORMANCE' = @{}};
foreach ($c in $counters) {
    $computerName, $key, $subKey = $c.Path.Replace('\\', '') -split '\\';
    $key = $key.ToUpper();
    $subKey = ($subKey -replace '\s+', '_').ToUpper();
    # each process has unique name => group by the common prefix
    if ($key -match '^process\(') {
        $subKey = $key;
        $key = 'PROCESS(*)';
    }
    if (!$toJson.'PERFORMANCE'.ContainsKey($key)) {
        $toJson.'PERFORMANCE'.$key = @{};  
    }
    $toJson.'PERFORMANCE'.$key.$subKey = $c.CookedValue;       
}

$serializer = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer;
$serializer.Serialize($toJson) |  Out-File $outfile;
# ConvertTo-JSON @($toJson) -Depth 10 | Out-File $outfile;
```

Note the last line in the code snippet is commented-out. [Although the documentation notes claim `ConvertTo-Json` is implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Json?view=powershell-5.1#notes) by using the [JavaScriptSerializer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), when I ran the cmdlet the JSON nested the `Hashtable` in an `array`. The potential downside, if you care about whitespace/formatting, is that `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize()` dumps everything into a one-line string.